# Auth0 Blazor Access to fetch at 'https://dev-xx.us.auth0.com/oauth/token' from origin 'https://xx.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: c#, azure, auth0, webassembly, .net-6.0

I'm working on a project where I implemented [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) authentication, and I've been able to do it correctly.

Login, Token Request, Call to my C# API with that token. All go well from my dev environment.

I Upload my SQL Database, C# API and Blazor App to Azure. The database and backend are working well, but I'm facing a issue when requesting the Token from the Blazor App when hosted on Azure, that I cannot find a solution for at the moment.

Here the complete message

`Access to fetch at 'https://dev-xxxxxxxx.us.auth0.com/oauth/token' from origin 'https://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

But when configure my Blazor App from Dev Environment to connect to my azure host API it work well, I mean the API return me the data requested.

I only get Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when I try to run my app when hosted on Azure.

I've added the https://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net' to the Auth0 application config in these two config options:

- Allowed Web Origins
- Allowed Origins (CORS)

Is there something that I miss?
Is there a bug in Auth0 related to .Net 6 / WASM?

Thanks Hugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw what went wrong in the Auth0 monitoring/Logs.
I added the Origin at the wrong Auth0 Application config.